# Getting data from drawed road using Google Map Android API V2

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm about to learn more on how to draw route between two points using Google Directions in Google Map Android API V2. My question is can i get informations about the drawed road like witch streets are passed by this road .Or can i get this information without drawing the route ? can i get it with the two points only(start- end).
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this is that you need?
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-travel-modes?hl=es-419

after @honeyyy comment I suggest this link
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-complex?hl=es-419

that get all checkpoint in the middle of two points an get information about them

Comment: Thank you for responding to me :) i want to know tthe streets tokens in the road between origin and destination .with drawing the road or without it

Comment: Thank you .your link is very helpfull  .do you have any other tutorials or articles to get deep in this API i'm a bigenner :)

Comment: I pretty sure that google documentation is better than this but... here you are
http://chrisholtz.com/blog/getting-started-with-the-google-maps-api/